# "new VpnApiClass()" get COM Exception 800701e7 till reboot

Tags: c#, com, cisco

I am using the CISCO COM object accessed via Interop.VpnApiLib in a C#, .NET2.0 project on Windows 8.1, 64 bit.

I create an instance of the class VpnApiClass from this library with the following line:

```
 vpnApiLib = new VpnApiClass();
```

Sometimes this line of code works, but too often, I get the following Exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {C15C0F4F-DDFB-4591-AD53-C9A71C9C15C0} failed due to the following
>   error: 800701e7.

Only a Windows reboot helps in such a situation.
I googled the error code, and found that it means

> "Error: attempt to access invalid address"

Does anyone know what to do to get round this error?

Comment: The underlying cause is a rock-hard exception, the equivalent of an AccessViolationException.  It occurs at a very critical time, just as the native DLL gets loaded and its DllMain() entrypoint runs.  You can see it in the Output window if you enable unmanaged debugging.  There isn't anything you can look at or do about if you don't have source code.  Cisco has source code, you'll need to call them.

Comment: Thank you Hans. I put the issue also into the Cisco support forum: https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12188291/c-new-vpnapiclass-get-com-exception-800701e7-till-reboot. But see the found workaround below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by another bug regarding a similar issue [here](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/error-loading-class-ocx-control-23532.aspx), we found a workaround. The DLL seems to have a fixed load address. When I load the DLL using `LoadLibrary()` right at program start, this address is free and ‘`new VpnApiClass()`’ works.

Comment: Very unlikely to be the true cause.  You've probably got a latent heap corruption bug in the program.  Ready to crash your code at any time after the corruption occurs, changing the load order merely hid the problem.  It will come back to haunt you sooner or later.